# Statement requires expression of scalar type (NSString invalid)

Tags: objective-c

I am a complete novice trying to take on more than I can chew, and have hit a problem that I just can't figure out.

I have tried to write a method in Xcode for choosing between two ways to start up an existing app, after I already created the second method.  The two options are  "startGame" and "startSkillzGame".

I am getting the error: "Statement requires expression of scalar type (NSString invalid)" where I have indicated in the code below.

I have read through dozens of questions relating to this error, looking for something that might be even vaguely relate to mine, but have come up empty.

I am not sure which other parts of the code I should quote to give you a more complete picture, but Im hoping that I am just being a stupid newbie and missing something obvious.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
-(BOOL) chooseGameMethod {

    NSArray *modesData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gamemodes" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for (NSString *line in modesData) {
        NSArray *modata = [[[line componentsSeparatedByString:@"//"] objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        NSString *modeName=[modata objectAtIndex:0];

        if  (*modeName; isEqualToString: @"CashGame";) {
//**********ERROR OCCURS HERE***************************************

            [(BOOL) startSkillzGame*]

        } else {

             [(BOOL) startGame*]
        }

    }
}
```

I also have a more general query.  The methods "startGame" and "startSkillzGame" are defined in the same file that I define "chooseGameMethod", where I then call them.  I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it.

I hope I am making at least some sense, and look forward to any input.

Comment: This is not Objective-C syntax. You probably want `if ([modeName isEqualToString:@"CashGame"]) { [self startSkillzGame]; } else { [self startGame]; }` You should probably learn the basics of the language before writing games (that involve cash)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and for pointing me in the right direction. Its all working now.  See how Im learning.  :)